# App started to crash after changing an icon

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, graphical-logo

Once I changed an **icon** of my app by right clicking on res folder and going to `New>Image` asset, app started to crash on my Android 6.0 device. Then I watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wPa8nQOKi4) that says that the 1st option "Launcher icon (Adaptive and Legacy)" is for Android 8.0 and *I didn't understand what he said*. And he said that "Launcher icon (Legacy only)" is for Android 7.1.1 and below. So, then I thought that the problem was that I used "Launcher icon (Adaptive and Legacy)" and my device is Android 6.0. Fortunately, I had backed up "mipmap" folders of default icon. But once I changed to default icon, my app is still crashing. Where a problem could be?

Comment: Please show **logcat** error logs.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm a begginer and I'm not sure if they are all error logs but they are all red except `09-28 12:54:47.204 12214-12214/com.example.myapp W/art: Attempted to destroy barrier with non zero count -1` which is black. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eEv_pmBDpro-FCezTASfnBl0AJOE4Ndj